# Symbol of South-West cross-product operator

Tags: math-operators, engineering

How can I ricreate this Mathematical symbol? I can't find this symbol anywhere.

The symbol is the following in picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, it only works in `\displaystyle`, but that can be fixed, if it need work in the smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,stackengine}
\newcommand\swcross{\mathbin{\mkern-5mu\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{.07ex}{\downarrow}{-\mkern-10mu-}
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}\mkern-5mu}}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\[
A \swcross B = C
\qquad
\fbox{$\swcross$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]